# ReferenceError: Datetime is not defined

Tags: apex, datetime, developer, sales

I'm trying to convert current time in hours and getting an error called DateTime not defined help from Anyone?

```
import { LightningElement,api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class GetTimeinHours extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

 handleSubmit(event){
 
            const fields = event.detail.fields;
            let rightNow = new Date();
            this.rolloverFlag = true;
            // Adjust for the user's time zone
            rightNow.setMinutes(
            new Date().getMinutes() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
            );
            // Return the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format
            let yyyyMmDd = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10);
            
            const CurrentTimeinHours = Datetime.now().hour();---------------> This line Causing an error, I'm trying converting current time in hours
            console.log('CurrentTimeinHours----->'+CurrentTimeinHours);

            if(fields.ET_Effective_Date__c === yyyyMmDd || CurrentTimeinHours < 11){

                fields.ET_Urgent_Flag__c = true;
            }
            else{
                console.log('Flag FALSE');
                fields.ET_Urgent_Flag__c = false;

            }
 }

}
```

Regards,
Chan

Comment: To get the current hour value try this:
`const dateObj = new Date();
        const currentHours = dateObj.getHours();
        console.log('currentHours ::' + currentHours);`

Comment: I am slightly confused. The `Date` value you get with "rightNow" is already in the browser's time zone, which will normally be the user time zone (depending on setup of course).

Comment: As the error suggests, there is no `Datetime` in Javascript. `Date` contains functionality for datetimes as well.